# A single subsubsection combines itself with the following bold text, does not happen anywhere else in the document

Tags: sectioning, bold, text

```
    \subsubsection{Inclusion and Exclusion Criteria}

\textbf{Inclusion Criteria}
```

This is the code that I have for a specific section in my thesis. In the preview it appears as " Inclusion and Exclusion Criteria  Inclusion Criteria" instead of being separated 
I've tried adding spaces, new lines, new pages! even between them, but they do not wish to separate. 
How can I fix this
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that we can try it out too. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: latex sections can be display or run in. What you describe is a run-in heading, the standard classes use display headings for section to subsubsection and run-in for paragraph and sub-paragraph but other classes may use run-in headings at higher level.